# Linux locate command copy path to clipboard

Tags: linux, terminal, command-prompt

hey for example I am going to change vhosts.conf

I first do locate it gives me multiple paths (my correct result is last one)
(**/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**)

then I select it with mouse and then write

**vim /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** to edit.

but what I want to do is locate the file and copy path to clipboard.
so in next line I'll only write vim and ctrl +v .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most terminal application you need to add <kbd>Maj</kbd> to the traditional copy and paste shortcut.

## Copy

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Maj</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

## Paste

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Maj</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

---

EDIT :

You can create a Bash function to automatically copy the n-th line of output to the clipboard.

For that install `xsel`

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

and add to your `~/.bahsrc` file

```
locateAndCopy() {
    locate $1 | sed -n $2p | xsel -i -b
}
```

Restart your terminal and now you can do

```
locateAndCopy something 1
```

And the 1st line of the locate result will be copied to clipboard using `xsel`.

Note that this is very minimal program, if your file cannot be found it will give errors. Maybe a better solution is to run locate and then decide which line to copy.

Comment: as I have mentioned it gives multiple paths not just one.otherwise I could actually do something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If `locate` gives you multiple path, how can it automatically know which one to copy?

Comment: I didnt say automaticly maybe locate function sends each line as an array so out of 3 if i type something like locate vhosts[2] I can get third line ?

Comment: You can do that using a bash alias for `locate` and `xclip`. Updating my answer...

Comment: Updated with an example. Altought it might not be optimal behaviour as   it can be hard to predict which line will be usefull to copy.

Comment: Unable to locate package xsel !..any other suggestion !